# Getting Token from Azure AD, Error: AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, token

i hope you guys have a great day!,

I in the middle of learning how to login with azure, and now, the popup and the auth is OK (i believe hehe), and i have the `code` response from the auth

and now, i need to get the `accessToken`, so i can get the user data (from who is sign-in), i try with this code:

```js
var requestParams: any = {
          client_id: "0b585496-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c0468796e718",
          scope: "User.Read",
          code: props.code, <-- this from `code` response
          redirect_uri: "myapp://login",
          grant_type: "authorization_code",
        };

        var formBody: any = [];
        for (var p in requestParams) {
          var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(p);
          var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(requestParams[p]);
          formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }

        formBody = formBody.join("&");

        /* make a POST request using fetch and the body params we just setup */
        let tokenResponse: any = null;
        fetch(
          `https://login.microsoftonline.com/afdb7f3a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4d604512e9f0/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            },
            body: formBody,
          }
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => {
            tokenResponse = response;
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```

and i get this error:

```
Object {
  "correlation_id": "94961159-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0c400f7d11e8",
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_codes": Array [
    50148,
  ],
  "error_description": "AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE.
Trace ID: dc2ba549-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8f961e9ba600
Correlation ID: 94961159-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0c400f7d11e8
Timestamp: 2022-07-21 05:25:40Z",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50148",
  "timestamp": "2022-07-21 05:25:40Z",
  "trace_id": "dc2ba549-909b-4446-8bb7-8f961e9ba600",
}
```

idk why i can't get the accessToken, my `code` looks like:
`0.AVUAOn_br_87QEeWJE1gRRLp8....oFkTkxc1DEhW31aXzd7IcylyCvaK2kjSR2XcDCsvHKUVubYiPCXjwY-D8SzZz883EhgZT8vx1mostM-_`

did you guys know, what wrong with my code? :(

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the error  ***"AADSTS50148: The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE"*** please try the following:

> **From the code given by you:**

```js
client_id: "0b585496-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c0468796e718",
scope: "User.Read",
code: props.code, <-- this from `code` response
redirect_uri: "myapp://login",
grant_type: "authorization_code",
```

Assuming that you are generating code from **`auth`** endpoint, Make sure the value of the **`code`** parameter is correct.

Make sure the request to the **`auth`** endpoint to generate the authorization code looks like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
response_type=code  
&client_id=Client_ID
&scope=Your_scope 
&redirect_uri=Your_Redirect_URI 
&code_challenge=Your_code_challenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

To generate the **`code_challenge`** you can make use of [**PKCE Generator Tool**](https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/) like below:

[image]

I am able to generate the **code value** from the browser of PKCE flow by using the above endpoint:

[image]

***And I am able to generate the access token successfully from Postman like below:***

[image]

To know more in detail, you can refer the below **link** to know how to do it programmatically:

[How to perform Auth Code with PKCE | Azure Active Directory Developer Support Team by Bac Hoang [MSFT]](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/performing-azure-ad-oauth2-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce-in-postman/)